# Given, "printf("%0.Xlf", somedouble);" where X is the amount of decimal places I want, how do I make X a variable?

Tags: variables, printf, decimal

I want to write

> printf("%0.2lf and %0.2lf", solution1, solution2);

were instead of 2 decimal places, I can use a variable, numberOfDecimalPlaces.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the man page for [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).

```
printf("%0.*lf and %0.*lf", numberOfDecimalPlaces, solution1, numberOfDecimalPlaces, solution2);
```

In one of the section it talks about variable width fields.

> The field width
>
> An optional decimal digit string (with nonzero first digit) specifying
> a minimum field width. If the converted value has fewer characters
> than the field width, it will be padded with spaces on the left (or
> right, if the left-adjustment flag has been given). Instead of a
> decimal digit string one may write "*" or "*m$" (for some decimal
> integer m) to specify that the field width is given in the next
> argument, or in the m-th argument, respectively, which must be of type
> int. A negative field width is taken as a '-' flag followed by a
> positive field width. In no case does a nonexistent or small field
> width cause truncation of a field; if the result of a conversion is
> wider than the field width, the field is expanded to contain the
> conversion result.